# Angular 2 Carousel Plugin 'carousel-component' is not a known element:

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement the plugin from here;

[Angular2-Carousel Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-carousel)

I am running the SPA Angular 2 template with Visual Studio 2017 Community. I have added the packages to my packages.json file and updated it to install the packages.

```
"angular2-carousel": "1.0.12",
"hammerjs": "2.0.8",
```

In my app.browser.module.ts I have;

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CarouselModule } from "angular2-carousel";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppModuleShared,
        CarouselModule
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

and then in the my Component.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CarouselModule } from "angular2-carousel";
import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from '../../../app.config';

@Component({
    selector: 'serviceSlider',
    templateUrl: './serviceSlider.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./serviceSlider.component.css']
})
export class ServiceSliderComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig) { }
}
```

and in the component.html I have;

```
<carousel-component>
    <div class="item-carousel">a</div>
    <div class="item-carousel">
        <div class="b">
            b
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-carousel">c</div>
    <div class="item-carousel">d</div>
</carousel-component>
```

however, when I run this I get the error;

> NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors: 'carousel-component'
>   is not a known element:
>   1. If 'carousel-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'carousel-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("

Comment: Try adding HammerJS to your .angular-cli.json's: "scripts": ["../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js"]

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio? I dont see this file anywhere?

Comment: That's because it's a hidden file. You probably have to enable it in visual studio, but visual studio is not needed to edit this though. You can just use notepad if you want

Comment: does webpack.config.vendor.js not replace this? as I can't find that file on a search anywhere in the solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you won't have the file if you didn't use the Angular CLI to create te project and I have no answer for "does webpack.config.vendor.js not replace this?" Sorry for not being able to help you